# get neighbors in distance 2 graph adjacency list in c

Tags: c, adjacency-list

I have created a graph using adjacency lists in c
The problem is that, I want to get and print only the neighbors that are in distance 2 of a given node. I tried BFS but it gets every node that a node can go. I know that if I have used adjacency matrix, I could just multiply the matrix with itself.

I used the code structure as below

```
// BFS algorithm in C

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define SIZE 40

struct queue {
  int items[SIZE];
  int front;
  int rear;
};

struct queue* createQueue();
void enqueue(struct queue* q, int);
int dequeue(struct queue* q);
void display(struct queue* q);
int isEmpty(struct queue* q);
void printQueue(struct queue* q);

struct node {
  int vertex;
  struct node* next;
};

struct node* createNode(int);

struct Graph {
  int numVertices;
  struct node** adjLists;
  int* visited;
};

// BFS algorithm
void bfs(struct Graph* graph, int startVertex) {
  struct queue* q = createQueue();

  graph->visited[startVertex] = 1;
  enqueue(q, startVertex);

  while (!isEmpty(q)) {
    printQueue(q);
    int currentVertex = dequeue(q);
    printf("Visited %d\n", currentVertex);

    struct node* temp = graph->adjLists[currentVertex];

    while (temp) {
      int adjVertex = temp->vertex;

      if (graph->visited[adjVertex] == 0) {
        graph->visited[adjVertex] = 1;
        enqueue(q, adjVertex);
      }
      temp = temp->next;
    }
  }
}

// Creating a node
struct node* createNode(int v) {
  struct node* newNode = malloc(sizeof(struct node));
  newNode->vertex = v;
  newNode->next = NULL;
  return newNode;
}

// Creating a graph
struct Graph* createGraph(int vertices) {
  struct Graph* graph = malloc(sizeof(struct Graph));
  graph->numVertices = vertices;

  graph->adjLists = malloc(vertices * sizeof(struct node*));
  graph->visited = malloc(vertices * sizeof(int));

  int i;
  for (i = 0; i < vertices; i++) {
    graph->adjLists[i] = NULL;
    graph->visited[i] = 0;
  }

  return graph;
}

// Add edge
void addEdge(struct Graph* graph, int src, int dest) {
  // Add edge from src to dest
  struct node* newNode = createNode(dest);
  newNode->next = graph->adjLists[src];
  graph->adjLists[src] = newNode;

  // Add edge from dest to src
  newNode = createNode(src);
  newNode->next = graph->adjLists[dest];
  graph->adjLists[dest] = newNode;
}

// Create a queue
struct queue* createQueue() {
  struct queue* q = malloc(sizeof(struct queue));
  q->front = -1;
  q->rear = -1;
  return q;
}

// Check if the queue is empty
int isEmpty(struct queue* q) {
  if (q->rear == -1)
    return 1;
  else
    return 0;
}

// Adding elements into queue
void enqueue(struct queue* q, int value) {
  if (q->rear == SIZE - 1)
    printf("\nQueue is Full!!");
  else {
    if (q->front == -1)
      q->front = 0;
    q->rear++;
    q->items[q->rear] = value;
  }
}

// Removing elements from queue
int dequeue(struct queue* q) {
  int item;
  if (isEmpty(q)) {
    printf("Queue is empty");
    item = -1;
  } else {
    item = q->items[q->front];
    q->front++;
    if (q->front > q->rear) {
      printf("Resetting queue ");
      q->front = q->rear = -1;
    }
  }
  return item;
}

// Print the queue
void printQueue(struct queue* q) {
  int i = q->front;

  if (isEmpty(q)) {
    printf("Queue is empty");
  } else {
    printf("\nQueue contains \n");
    for (i = q->front; i < q->rear + 1; i++) {
      printf("%d ", q->items[i]);
    }
  }
}

int main() {
  struct Graph* graph = createGraph(6);
  addEdge(graph, 0, 1);
  addEdge(graph, 0, 2);
  addEdge(graph, 1, 2);
  addEdge(graph, 1, 4);
  addEdge(graph, 1, 3);
  addEdge(graph, 2, 4);
  addEdge(graph, 3, 4);

  bfs(graph, 0);

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: You need to seed the queue with all of the neighbors of the starting node, and then run the BFS without adding any more nodes to the queue.

Comment: @user3386109 i updated the code with the current bfs algorithm i use

Comment: You can make a copy of the `while (temp)` loop to enqueue the neighbors of the starting vertex. And then run the `while (!isEmpty(q))` loop, but remove the `enqueue(q, adjVertex)` call from the `while (temp)` loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a `distance` array to keep track of it.

Set distance of starting node as 0. Every time you enqueue a new node, update the distance of that node to the distance of its parent + 1. Print the nodes where distance[vertex] == 2.

```
void bfs( ... ) {
  ...
  distance[startVertex] = 0;
  while (!isEmpty(q)) { 
    int currentVertex = dequeue(q);
    ....
    while (temp) {
      ....
      if (graph->visited[adjVertex] == 0) {
        graph->visited[adjVertex] = 1;
        enqueue(q, adjVertex);
        distance[adjVertex] = distance[currentVertex] + 1;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: i tried but it seems not to work, im not sure what im doing wrong see above

Comment: @cstac `distance[adjnumber] = distance[adjnumber] + 1;` is wrong. Should be `distance[currentnumber] + 1`.

Comment: oh sorry, ok i corrected this. but where do i print? after while?

Comment: @user3009403 Upto you. You can do it after the `while (!isEmpty(q))` loop or you can do it right after the `dist[] = dist[] + 1` line or you can return the distance array and print it in `main`.

Comment: thanks, it works now but there is a problem. the program shows the menu until user enter option 5 and then it terminates. If i use bfs function (which is option 4) twice or more, only the first time of it's use shows correct results

Comment: @user3009403 I have to see the code for that but generally if something works the first time but not the second time or more, it means some variable(s) is not being reset before the next run. Is `graph->visited` being reset?

Comment: right! I noticed that too after some time. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

1. Let **N** be the node you are interested in findind the distance.
2. Put every element that is accesible directly from **N** into a list/queue.
3. Mark every element as not being reachable (false).
4. For every element added in step 2, check their adjacency list and mark the nodes that are accesible as reachable(true).
5. Check which nodes are reachable.

The pseudocode:

```
 queue<nodes> Q = EMPTY
 for each node N reachable from START NODE:
      enqueue N in Q
 array<bool> IS_REACHABLE = FALSE (for all nodes)
 for each node N in Q:
      go through the adjacency list of N and mark TRUE in array iS_REACHABLE for every element reachable from N
      remove N from Q
```

The elements of array IS_REACHABLE that are TRUE will be your answer.

Comment: so its a variation of bfs? i updated the code with the current bfs algorithm i use

Comment: Yes, the strategy is similar to the traditional bfs algorithm. You could call it bfs with a little 'twist'.

Comment: can you do a pseudo code based on the bfs function above?
im not sure how to make each element not reachable